# How to insert a new node in a link list like structure?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to insert 2.5 between 2 and 3 in this linklist-like structure.

```
class edge_model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ymax = None
        self.xmin = None
        self.dx = None
        self.edge_next = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1 = edge_model()
    e2 = edge_model()
    e3 = edge_model()
    e_in = edge_model()
    e1.dx = 1
    e2.dx = 2
    e3.dx = 3
    e_in.dx = 2.5

    e1.edge_next = e2
    e2.edge_next = e3
    e3.edge_next = None

    p = e1
    while p.edge_next:
        if e_in.dx < p.edge_next.dx:
        e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
        p.edge_next = e_in
        break
    else:
        p = p.edge_next.edge_next

    print e1.dx
    print e1.edge_next.dx
    print e1.edge_next.edge_next.dx
    print "====="
```

Why is the result of outputs not `1 -> 2 -> 2.5-> 3`? and how to make it?  Some change. But the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your move to the next node statement:

```
p.edge_next = p.edge_next.edge_next
```

Should be:

```
p = p.edge_next
```

#### Test Code:

```
class edge_model:
    def __init__(self, dx):
        self.ymax = None
        self.xmin = None
        self.dx = dx
        self.edge_next = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1 = edge_model(1)
    e2 = edge_model(2)
    e3 = edge_model(3)
    e_in = edge_model(2.5)

    e1.edge_next = e2
    e2.edge_next = e3

    p = e1
    while p.edge_next:
        if e_in.dx < p.edge_next.dx:
            e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
            p.edge_next = e_in
            break
        else:
            p = p.edge_next

    print("===")
    print(e1.dx)
    print(e1.edge_next.dx)
    print(e1.edge_next.edge_next.dx)
```

#### Results:

```
===
1
2
2.5
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the wrong place, your answer is definite right. Can you see my question again, I just altered some of the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I will put the question onto a new one. thanks

Comment: There is the link and I will edit this one back.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980843/how-to-insert-a-new-node-in-a-link-list-like-structure-another-one

Comment: Wow, I just confused about how to mart the answer as accepted. You are very helpful. Can you help me figure this one out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980843/how-to-insert-a-new-node-in-a-link-list-like-structure-another-one