# How to insert a new node in a link list like structure? Another one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to insert 2.5 between 2 and 3 in this linkedist structure.

```
class edge_model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ymax = None
        self.xmin = None
        self.dx = None
        self.edge_next = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1 = edge_model()
    e2 = edge_model()
    e3 = edge_model()
    e_in = edge_model()
    e1.dx = 1
    e2.dx = 2
    e3.dx = 3
    e_in.dx = 2.5

    e1.edge_next = e2
    e2.edge_next = e3
    e3.edge_next = None

    p = e1
    while p.edge_next:
        if e_in.dx > p.dx:
            p = p.edge_next
            continue
        break

    e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
    p.edge_next = e_in.edge_next

    print e1.dx
    print e1.edge_next.dx
    print e1.edge_next.edge_next.dx
    print "====="
```

Why is the result of outputs not `1 -> 2 -> 2.5-> 3`? and how to make it so?

Another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980187/how-to-insert-a-new-node-in-a-link-list-like-structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two errors in your code.  First you go one step too far with:

```
if e_in.dx > p.edge_next.dx:
```

should be:

```
if e_in.dx > p.dx:
```

and then you update the wrong link with:

```
e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
p.edge_next = e_in.edge_next
```

should be:

```
e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
p.edge_next = e_in
```

#### Full listing:

```
class edge_model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ymax = None
        self.xmin = None
        self.dx = None
        self.edge_next = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1 = edge_model()
    e2 = edge_model()
    e3 = edge_model()
    e_in = edge_model()
    e1.dx = 1
    e2.dx = 2
    e3.dx = 3
    e_in.dx = 2.5

    e1.edge_next = e2
    e2.edge_next = e3
    e3.edge_next = None

    p = e1
    while p.edge_next:
        if e_in.dx > p.edge_next.dx:
            p = p.edge_next
            continue
        break

    e_in.edge_next = p.edge_next
    p.edge_next = e_in

    p = e1
    print(p.dx)
    while p.edge_next:
        p = p.edge_next
        print(p.dx)
    print("=====")
```

#### Results:

```
1
2
2.5
3
=====
```